# Find the number of non zero values in 2 columns of np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a **np.array** with numbers. I need to count the number of values which are **non zero** in both columns.

**Example:**

```
col1 = (1, 0, 2, 0, 8)
col2 = (0, 1, 6, 0, 9)
```

**Result:**

2 as only (2,6) and (8,9) rows are ok.

**My version(But this is too slow):**

```python
both_num = 0 
for k in range(matrix[:, i].shape[0]):
  if matrix[:, i][k] != 0 and matrix[:, j][k] != 0:
    both_num += 1
```

Comment: Please add any attempts you have made (working or not) and the community will help refine the technique.

Comment: Are you after `np.sum((a!= 0).all(0))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
col1 = (1, 0, 2, 0, 8)
col2 = (0, 1, 6, 0, 9)
c =  map(lambda col_1, col_2: col_1 and col_2, col1, col2)

import numpy as np
print np.count_nonzero([c])
```

or

```
# thx to @AChampion
np.count_nonzero(col1*col2)
```

Comment: `np.count_nonzero(col1*col2)` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 8], [0, 1, 6, 0, 9]])
# array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 8],
#        [0, 1, 6, 0, 9]])
a.all(axis=0)
# array([False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then all you need is to sum it:

```
np.sum(a.all(axis=0))
# 2
```

Similarly, if your array is transposed,

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 8], [0, 1, 6, 0, 9]]).T
# array([[1, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [2, 6],
#        [0, 0],
#        [8, 9]])
np.sum(a.all(axis=1))
# 2
```